# How do I move the variable referencing this array back one?

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe

I'm creating this fail-safe for identifying dates that shifts to the previous date in the array if the dataframe I'm working with doesn't contain the date. I have everything setup, I'm simply trying to understand how I can move the `date` variable from `nav_dates_array[1]` to `nav_dates_array[0]` without having to call from `nav_dates_arr` again. I thought a simple `date.shift(1)` would work but that is not the case.  Know this is basic so apologies but I hope you can help! Thank you!

```
nav_dates_arr = ['01-02-2020', '01-03-2020', '01-06-2020', '01-07-2020', '01-08-2020', '01-09-2020', '01-10-2020',
          '01-13-2020', '01-14-2020', '01-15-2020', '01-16-2020', '01-17-2020', '01-21-2020', '01-22-2020',
          '01-23-2020', '01-24-2020', '01-27-2020', '01-28-2020', '01-29-2020', '01-30-2020', '01-31-2020']

date = nav_dates_array[1]
```

here is the full code:

```
nav_dates_arr = ['2020-01-02', '01-03-2020', '01-06-2020', '01-07-2020', '01-08-2020', '01-09-2020', '01-10-2020',
          '01-13-2020', '01-14-2020', '01-15-2020', '01-16-2020', '01-17-2020', '01-21-2020', '01-22-2020',
          '01-23-2020', '01-24-2020', '01-27-2020', '01-28-2020', '01-29-2020', '01-30-2020', '01-31-2020']


def get_holdings_df_date(d):
    if str(d)in str(holdings_df['Date'].values):
        return holdings_df.loc[holdings_df['Date'] == d]
    else:
        return holdings_df.loc[holdings_df['Date'] == d]

   # return the row for the sent date using holdings_df.loc[holdings_df['Date'] == d]
   # if that date is missing, return the prior date
print(get_holdings_df_date(nav_dates_arr[0]))
system.exit()
```

where I'm trying to get the else statement to return d from the last position in the array.

Comment: nav_dates_arr= pd.date_range('1/2/2020', periods = 30, freq ='D') could initialize that array easier.
    nav_dates_arr=nav_dates_arr.shift(-1, freq ='D')  can shift the array by one to the left afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, not sure if it is what you are looking for, is to store the array index as a variable. For example:

```
date_index = 1
```

Then you can get the current date like this always:

```
nav_dates_arr[date_index]
```

If you do `date_index = date_index - 1`, then this will "shift" your index left. But you will still need to use `nav_dates_arr[date_index]` to "get" the value.

If you wanted to get fancy and really have something like `date.shift(1)` you can implement your own `Class` that takes an array of dates in the constructor, keeps a `current_index` pointer, and has a `shift` method that moves the index left one (subtracts by 1).

Comment: I just updated my code at the top. I'm hoping that it helps better explain because i'm confused now.

Comment: okay... sorry it didn't really help. I don't understand what you're trying to do at all. It looks like the variable `nav_dates_arr` is not used. It would help to see what your input data is and what you'd like to get as output or return value, whether that be a date, position in array, or boolean.

Comment: what is the structure of `holdings_df`, it isn't clear.

Comment: It's a dataframe full of financial information that I grabbed online. I'm basically trying to match the dates to holdings_df. if the if statement doesn't match up then i'm trying to get the else statement to instead return the previous date in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this then?

```
nav_dates_arr = ['2020-01-02', '01-03-2020', '01-06-2020', '01-07-2020', '01-08-2020', '01-09-2020', '01-10-2020',
          '01-13-2020', '01-14-2020', '01-15-2020', '01-16-2020', '01-17-2020', '01-21-2020', '01-22-2020',
          '01-23-2020', '01-24-2020', '01-27-2020', '01-28-2020', '01-29-2020', '01-30-2020', '01-31-2020']

holdings_df = {}  # defined elsewhere...

def get_holdings_df_date(dates_arr, try_index=1):
    while try_index in dates_arr:  # keep going until we get index out of bounds
        if dates_arr[try_index] in holdings_df['Date'].values:  # see if our selected date is in the values list
            return dates_arr[try_index]  # if it is, great! return the date
        try_index = try_index - 1  # wasn't found, let's move our index to the left, and try again (loop)
    return None  # Nothing was found :(

print(get_holdings_df_date(nav_dates_arr, 1))
system.exit()
```

Comment: There isn't anyway to just ```return holdings_df.loc[holdings_df['Date'] == d].shift(-1)``` up a row in holdings_df for the else statement? to find the previous row in the holdings_df